# try to install the minerl module for python langage: Error: legacy-install-failure

Tags: python-3.x, java-8, compiler-errors, windows-10

I am on windows10 with python version 3.10.1 and trying to install the module minerl for python but it return the error :

```
`> Task :compileJava FAILED

      FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

      * What went wrong:
      Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
      > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361 contains a valid JDK installation.`
```

I have Java 8 update 361 (x64) and Java SE Developpement Kit 8 Update 361.

The end of the log of the command python.exe -m pip install minerl is :

```
`
BUILD FAILED in 5m 48s
      20 actionable tasks: 20 executed
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-61k4nuvk\minerl_e8c585976cc144989e513c08059a2d1d\setup.py", line 167, in <module>
          setuptools.setup(
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 580, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
          self.build()
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-61k4nuvk\minerl_e8c585976cc144989e513c08059a2d1d\setup.py", line 88, in build
          build_minecraft(MALMO_DIR, os.path.join(
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-61k4nuvk\minerl_e8c585976cc144989e513c08059a2d1d\setup.py", line 141, in build_minecraft
          subprocess.check_call('{} -g run/gradle shadowJar'.format(gradlew).split(' '))
        File "C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['gradlew.bat', '-g', 'run/gradle', 'shadowJar']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      building Minecraft from  C:\Users\Trinometra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-61k4nuvk\minerl_e8c585976cc144989e513c08059a2d1d\minerl\Malmo, build dir: build\lib\minerl\Malmo
      copying source dir
      CALLING SETUP.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> minerl`
```

I tried install the module minerl to start develop minecraft smart bots but it doesn t work.
I first try reinstall JDK and Java but it didn t change anything.

Answer (score 0):

%JAVA_HOME% wasn t setted as my java jdk path, the probleme is solved